# How do I make the output of the openai api response that gets displayed more comprehensible rather than it just being a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, openai-api

I am doing a personal project where a user enters specifications to generate a workout. I used jQuery's $.ajax function to send a POST request to the OpenAI API endpoint. However, the output of the AI onto the user interface is in paragraph form which is annoying to read and understand. How do I have the output on the user interface look more readable and easy to take in?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WorkoutWizard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/91ced6fe6d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="title-container">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-hat-wizard"></i>
            <div class="title">WorkoutWizard</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main-card">
            <div class="settings">
                <form>
                    <div class="name spec">
                        <label>Name:</label>     
                        <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="level spec">
                        <label>Current Fitness Level:</label>
                        <ul class="level-options">
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" name="level" id="radio">
                                <label>Beginner</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" name="level" id="radio">
                                <label>Intermediate</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" name="level" id="radio">
                                <label>Advanced</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="duration spec">
                        <label for="workoutDuration">Workout Duration (minutes):</label>
                        <input type="number" id="workoutDuration" name="workoutDuration" min="10" max="120" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="muscles spec">
                        <label>Targeted Muscles (1-2):</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleChest" name="muscles" value="chest">
                                <label for="muscleChest">Chest</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleBack" name="muscles" value="back">
                                <label for="muscleBack">Back</label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleShoulders" name="muscles" value="shoulders">
                                <label for="muscleShoulders">Shoulders</label>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleArms" name="muscles" value="arms">
                                <label for="muscleArms">Arms</label>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleGlutes" name="muscles" value="glutes">
                                <label for="muscleGlutes">Glutes</label>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleLegs" name="muscles" value="legs">
                                <label for="muscleLegs">Legs</label>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleAbs" name="muscles" value="abs">
                                <label for="muscleAbs">Abdominals</label>    
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleLowerBack" name="muscles" value="lowerBack">
                                <label for="muscleLowerBack">Lower Back</label>  
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="muscleCardio" name="muscles" value="muscleCardio">
                                <label for="muscleCardio">Cardio</label>    
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="exercise spec">
                        <label for="exercise">Exercise Type:</label>
                        <select id="exercise" name="exercise" required>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Exercise Type</option>
                          <option value="strength">Strength</option>
                          <option value="hypertrophy">Hypertrophy</option>
                          <option value="functional">Functional</option>
                          <option value="hiit">High-intensity interval training (HIIT)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button">
                        <a href="#" class="btn41-43 btn-43">
                            Generate Workout
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                <div id="loadingAnimation" class="loading-animation"></div>
                <div class="message-content" id="generatedWorkout"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@800&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
    height: 85vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.main-card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #ff5252;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 10px solid  #ff7b7b;
}

.settings {
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-radius: 2.5px 0 0 2.5px;
    padding: 15px;
}

form {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;
}

.level {
    display: flex;
}


.level ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.muscles {
    display: flex;
}

.muscles ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.spec {
    color: white;
}

.spec input {
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.btn41-43 {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .btn-43 {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .btn-43:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .btn-43:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  .btn-43:hover:after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

.message {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 65%;
}

.message-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.loading-animation {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none; /* Initially hide the loading animation */
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.title-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="muscles"]');
        
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
          checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="muscles"]:checked');
            
            if (checkedCheckboxes.length > 2) {
              this.checked = false; // Prevent checking more than 2 checkboxes
            }
            
            if (checkedCheckboxes.length < 1) {
              this.checked = true; // Ensure at least 1 checkbox is checked
            }
          });
        });
    });

    // Add an event listener to the "Generate Workout" button
    document.querySelector('.btn41-43').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

        showLoadingAnimation();
        
        // Gather user inputs
        var userName = document.getElementById('user-name').value;
        var fitnessLevel = document.querySelector('input[name="level"]:checked').value;
        var workoutDuration = document.getElementById('workoutDuration').value;
        var selectedMuscles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="muscles"]:checked')).map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
        var exerciseType = document.getElementById('exercise').value;

        // Construct the message object
        var message = {
            "role": "user",
            "content": `Generate a workout routine for ${userName} with fitness level ${fitnessLevel}, targeting ${selectedMuscles.join(', ')} muscles, lasting ${workoutDuration} minutes, and focusing on ${exerciseType} exercises. (Keep response to about 100 words max)`
        };

        // Send request to OpenAI API
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                "messages": [message],
                "temperature": 0.7
            }),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer API-KEY');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                // Handle the result as needed (e.g., update the UI with the generated workout)
                hideLoadingAnimation();
                displayGeneratedWorkout(result.choices[0].message.content);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                hideLoadingAnimation();
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });

    function showLoadingAnimation() {
        // Show the loading animation
        var loadingAnimationElement = document.getElementById('loadingAnimation');
        loadingAnimationElement.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideLoadingAnimation() {
        // Hide the loading animation
        var loadingAnimationElement = document.getElementById('loadingAnimation');
        loadingAnimationElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function displayGeneratedWorkout(workoutContent) {
        // Clear the previous workout content
        var generatedWorkoutElement = document.getElementById('generatedWorkout');
        generatedWorkoutElement.innerHTML = '';

        // Update the content of the element with the new generated workout
        generatedWorkoutElement.innerHTML = `<p>${workoutContent}</p>`;
    }
});
```

I guess I wanted the output to be a list of the workouts for the routine. Something like how chatGPT would output it.